# How to use Yii::$app->language

Tags: internationalization, yii2

I'm hard to know what is the ideal place to use the `**\Yii::$app->language = 'pt';**`

I tried in `main.php` view, but only the menu got the translation. In the [tutorial-i18N](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-i18n.md) says:

> You may set the application language at runtime to the language that
>   the user has chosen. This has to be done at a point before any output
>   is generated so that it affects all the output correctly. Therefor
>   just change the application property to the desired value

My intention is to store the desired language in a `LANGUAGE` field in the user profile (along with `FULL_NAME`, etc.).

In the code, I need to know the correct location and how to use the same.

**EDIT**

@Timothée Planchais, this way works:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
        public function init()
        {
        parent::init();

        if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->user->identity->profile->language;
        }
        }
```

But work only in SiteController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the application language, edit the file config/web.php :

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'myapp',
    'name' => My App',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language' => 'pt',//HERE
    ...
]
```

---

You can do all in a custom Controller class which should be extended by all your controllers. In the `init()` function :

```
namespace app\components;

class Controller extends yii\web\Controller
{
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
      Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->language = Yii::$app->language;
    }
  }

}
```

SiteController for example :

```
class SiteController extends app\components\Controller
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Timothée, this worked, but I have to do in each CONTROLLER in my application?

Comment: Yes, all your controllers have to extend this custom app\components\Controller.